# Does anyone know the temperature ranges one can expect on a core2 duo

Tags: cpu, temperature

Some background.
I'm having problems with my computer suddenly shutting down and then refusing to start unless I wait awhile. So I'm assuming it's a temperature problem.

I installed [SpedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) and it showed System 48C and CPU 50C it shut down again shortly after. I have since the removed the side of my computer for better airflow.

I have an Intel Core 2 Duo E8500 3.16GHz with a stock fan
**I'd like to know the ranges it should *feel comfortable* in.**

Celsius please.
(And please do include some references/links)

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all the answers. As the cpu-temp wasn't the problem I started poking about a bit more inside my computer and touched something very hot. My new suspect (as someone noted) is the PSU is to blame. I cant feel any exhaust in the back of it (it has a 120mm fan) and i put a thermometer on it for a few minutes and it was 54C on the outside.

**EDIT2:** Conclusion
As the computer was still under warranty I took it back to the shop for service and they gave me a new PSU.

Comment: If its Bailing under 60, your problems sure ain't directly overtemp related. Electrics most likely  to blame imho. Please report PSU Brand name, that component has in my experience been the #1 cause of computer problems.

Comment: Superb question and perfect answer(s) +1 .. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max case temperature is 72.4C. The processor itself will likely be hotter than that. (source: http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SLB9L#).

If your software is reporting a core temp of 50C you should be fine.

If you have added additional hard drives, a beefier video card or more power thirsty RAM, it may be that your power supply is too small (too low wattage). Other potential causes are bad sticks of RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Intel lists this processor's Thermal Specification as 72.4, here: http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SLAPK#.

I've heard a rule of thumb "keep it under 75C".  Most processors should operate perfectly at 50C.

Comment: BTW, Tcase temperature is measured at the IHS or that metal casing protecting the core on your processor, which is what your BIOS will report.  Core or Tjunction temperatures will show a higher temp.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the actual range for this CPU, but in general, I doubt temperature is your problem.

50°C is far from being a high temperature for a CPU, it's rather a normal one (for a small activity). As comparison, my T7400, in my laptop, can spike to 80-85°C without the computer to reboot (ok, it might reboot at 85...). It's a laptop, and a different CPU, but that gives an idea of the range.

So or the issue is not the temperature, or your CPU temperature probe has a problem, in my opinion (rather the first choice).

Comment: my T9300 goes from 45°C to 95°C, I was scared when it got that hot, but it keeps on trucking.

Comment: yea even my dell xps can easily get up to 74C without much going on. i had to install some software to put the computer in power saving mode to keep the temp below 60C, is there something wrong with my T7400?

Comment: @melaos: It's more likely that you have a process using CPU all the time, leaving it on full speed, and obviously rather a cooling issue, like fans turning on really late. Try I8kfan for your xps, to see when fans are turning on, see if you can adjust the trigger temperatures better. Besides, try to clean your fans, it helps a lot, especially after a long time using it and exposing it to dust.