# Safe temperature range for a Core 2 Quad CPU?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, multi-core

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anyone know the temperature ranges one can expect on a core2 duo](https://superuser.com/questions/20267/does-anyone-know-the-temperature-ranges-one-can-expect-on-a-core2-duo)

I've looked around for an answer to this for a while, and have found many conflicting answers. I've heard that it shouldn't be allowed to go higher than 45C or so, and I've also heard that 55C is a safe limit. I'd really appreciate some clarification.

Comment: I've seen duplicate questions mentioning particular models of CPUs chips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the individual CPU, take a look at the [Intel Core 2 Quad Specification site](http://ark.intel.com/ProductCollection.aspx?familyID=28398)  and click on your CPU to find out.

It looks like average thermal specification is between 60c-70c, with some being higher

Comment: Looks like 71.4 for my Q8400, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Usually anything in the 40-60 range is safe. If you hit the 60s or 70s you need to check your cooling solution. I believe most motherboards (double check yours) have a fail safe now where if your temp reaches a certain threshold, your system will power off.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere from 25C to 55C is safe.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you are doing on the computer.

*Example*: Recoding a Blu-ray movie from 50GB to 25GB. In that case, the CPU reaches temperatures of 90C - 95C.

You need strong fans to pull out the heat or the CPU may burn or system halts.